# SQL Injection ByPass

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE password="'.$_GET['password'].'"');
if($result->fetchArray()) $step1=true;

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE password=\''.$_GET['password'].'\'');
if($result->fetchArray()) $step2=true;

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE password='.$_GET['password']);
if($result->fetchArray()) $step3=true;
```

This code is part of a ctf challenge I'm doing strictly for learning purposes and I'm not quite sure how to get each of these SQL statements to evaluate as true.

Some thoughts i had was doing an insert statement where the password would equal the injection statement but I'm not sure if thats a good approach. If its possibile i would like to get it without modification to the backend database.

I'm not really looking for a direct answer, but perhaps some guidance.

Appreciate the help.

**EDIT**: $step1, $step2 and $step3 need to all evaluate to true

Comment: For the first one you use double quotes, second one single quotes, third one you can use any. So something like " or 1=1, ' or 1=1, "" or 1=1

Comment: right, but you can only inject 1 payload. You dont submit 3 different payloads to the application. So 1 payload has to satisfy all 3

Answer (score 0):

The **OWASP Foundation** website is a rich source for *information security* topics.

They have a page designated to **SQL Injection Bypassing**.

Your target is that you need to make sure that however the query has been constructed, the result will be a **true** value.

An example that was provided by OWASP was the following:

`select * from table where id = 1 AND if((ascii(lower(substring((select user()),$i,1))))!=$s,1,benchmark(200000,md5(now())))`

Most website's that take their data seriously have means of protecting their databases from all sorts of *Injection attacks*, a basic one being *input sanitisation*.

**Reference:**
SQL Injection Bypassing WAF - OWASP. (2018). Owasp.org. Retrieved 8 April 2018, from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Bypassing_WAF

Comment: I don't see how that would work. I don't see where you'd escape out of the single quote (') or the double quote (") with that payload. That may work for the 3rd condition.